# Never store intermediate program state in DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to run into [this funny bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948913/my-website-keeps-crashing-ie-cant-debug) the other day where too quick modifications of the DOM caused the entire internet explorer to crash. So i was thinking, why am i even setting these values if i'm going to change them later anyway?  (the modifications are very unpredictable so completely avoiding the scenario is impossible)

Some background, my website is more like a game/application and has alot of custom elements etc. Performance is key and moving around and modifying objects should be fast, smooth and without flicker. In one iteration tons of objects can have their state modified.

The objects in my application right now follows something similar to this pattern. domElement is the actual element used in the DOM, created with document.createElement or getElementById.

```
function SetWidth(w) {
  this.width = w;
  this.domElement.style.width = w + "px";
}
```

Obiously an object has more styles than just width but just to simplify things. This works pretty well right now but what if i for some reason set the width of one object twice inside one "program loop". This will mean the DOM will be modified twice but it's only the second state that should be displayed. In most new browsers this doesn't make a difference because the page is not rendered until all user javascript has completed. But in some browsers you can get updates unpredictably anytime. And even if there is no visible change, does it impact the performance?

Another problem is that some elements depend on being attached to the DOM before you can set/get some properties on them which you can easier avoid with the pattern below.

What i was thinking of doing instead was going back to the old-school render-loop pattern.
So the above object would look like this:

```
function SetWidth(w) {
  this.width = w;
  this.stateChanged = true;
}
function Render() {
  if(this.stateChanged)
      this.domElement.style.width = this.width + "px";
}
```

Once the "program-loop" is done you loop through every object only to "render" them (or use some more sophisticated structure keeping track of all modified objects).

To me this seems like defeating the whole purpose of having the DOM as you are basically reinventing what is already in place but sometimes it feels like it doesn't work properly so you have to roll your own version.

Has anyone used something similar and is it worth it? What are the pros and cons? What else do i have to think of? Adding and removing objects and managing z-index also should be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to watch out for is that if you request the value of property that is dependant on the layout, the browser will recalculate the layout to get the value, which may take a significant amount of time. So "this.style.width = '80px'" will be quick but "this.style.width = '80px'; var wid = this.clientWidth;" will take much, much longer. Of course, if you use the setWidth/render pattern above, you won't be able to get the value of 
clientWidth until after the render phase.

The setWidth/render pattern is a reasonable one for your use case, but I'd create a sub object to hold the pending layout values rather than storing them directly on the 'this' object. If you empty/recreate the sub object at the end of the render step, you won't need to store a separate stateChanged variable, the presence of the property in the sub object can serve that purpose.